# Can I decorate a parent class and make the children classes use its decorator automatically?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, decorator

I have the following structure for a Base Repository (Parent):

```
public interface IBaseRepository<TEntity, TId> where TEntity : class, IEntity<TId>

public class BaseRepository<TEntity, TId> : IRepository<TEntity, TId>
```

Then I have the following structure for a specific repository (Children) that inherits the base one:

```
public interface IUserRepository : IRepository<User,Guid>

public class UserRepository<User,Guid> : BaseRepository<User,Guid>, IUserRepository
```

Is it possible to registrate the decorator bellow for the parent class, and make its methods take effect when calling the child classes?

```
public class BaseRepositoryDecorator<TEntity, TId> : IRepository<TEntity, TId>
```

If I create a **UserRepositoryDecorator** and then inherit from **BaseRepositoryDecorator** and register it using SimpleInjector or Scrutor it works.

But is it possible to do the same without having to create a *"children"RepositoryDecorator* (like the UserRepositoryDecorator) for each children?

Comment: As a thought experiment, try to remove the use of the (MS.DI) DI Container from the picture and create the object structure you wish to have by hand. If you can't make the code compile when hand-written, you know what you wish is impossible with a DI Container as well. Can you update your question and show a code example of the object structure you wish to have? e.g. I'd like to see something like `new UserService(new BaseRepositoryDecorator<User,Guid>(new UserRepository()))`.

Comment: Also, please review your code and make sure the code samples compile; make them into a [Minimal Resproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). (tip: also add constructors to show the dependencies).